# How to add an user to sysadmin role using ALTER ROLE?

Tags: sql-server

'sa' user when executing the below script, the following error message is shown.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT LOGINNAME FROM MASTER.DBO.SYSLOGINS WHERE NAME = N'p_sys')
BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN [p_sys] WITH PASSWORD=N'test', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF;
    ALTER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER p_sys;
END

Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Cannot alter the role 'sysadmin', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

I do not want to use sp_addsrvrolemember because MS says it is [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750.aspx).

Please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`alter role`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189775.aspx) is for database roles, but `sysadmin` is server role.   Try [`alter server role`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677634.aspx) instead:

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE server_role_name ADD MEMBER p_sys
```